# How to reference completing a previous academic major in a resume?

Tags: resume, skills

I am preparing to complete a bachelor's degree in computer science, but previously completed all of the requirements for a major in business/CIS before switching to computer science. It included the typical business courses such as marketing, macro/micro, accounting, finance, law, etc. I also completed a strategic management capstone. (I will have completed two capstones when all is said and done)

My school only allows double-majors within the same discipline (arts, science, business) so they cannot be combined in one degree. The school doesn't offer academic minors. A second degree requires gaining 30 credits *after* graduation whereas these are already completed. The coursework does not align with any undergraduate certificate offered. They offer a lower level associates degree in general management but I am a mid-career adult with enough public-sector management training and experience behind me that a lower level degree is unnecessary.

I would like to call out this higher level coursework on my resume somehow as it can be relevant to my future career. But I'm unsure how to actually reference it on the resume. I've considered placing it at the end in a section containing miscellaneous info, but have also seen the word *cognate* used in reference to majors and minors in the education section. For example see the education section of [this resume from a Mozilla engineer](https://msu.edu/~weinjare/resume/resume.html).

What is the best way to highlight this correctly in my resume?

Answer (score 2):

Recruiters don't really care what the exact title of your degree is. You can put what you want on your resume (computer + business) as long as you can prove it : do you have an official record of attending and passing the class? If yes, there is no issue.

Moreover, you stated that you are a mid-career, so if you have 15 years of work experience, your degree doesn't really matter, your experience does.

As the format, go on a job board, look at the resume of other people that have the job you want to apply for and take the best of it ( you will see if the business part is important or not).

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking. Just wondered if there was one specific way to state it or not. Thanks.